# Return rows that have one value but not another

Tags: mysql

For every same date (this is just one section of the table), I want to return the account numbers that made a purchase of A but DID NOT purchase B, and another query for vice-versa. So running the first query for A but no B should return 2 and 5. Running the vice-versa query for B but no A should give me 4. Thanks for the help. I'm assuming I would have to do a join of some sorts on the table but I'm stuck.

```
+----+----------------+---------------+----------+--+--+
| ID | Account Number | Purchase Type |   Date   |  |  |
+----+----------------+---------------+----------+--+--+
|  1 |              1 | A             | 20140301 |  |  |
|  1 |              1 | A             | 20140301 |  |  |
|  1 |              1 | B             | 20140301 |  |  |
|  2 |              2 | A             | 20140301 |  |  |
|  3 |              3 | A             | 20140301 |  |  |
|  3 |              3 | B             | 20140301 |  |  |
|  4 |              4 | B             | 20140301 |  |  |
|  5 |              5 | A             | 20140301 |  |  |
|  5 |              5 | A             | 20140301 |  |  |
+----+----------------+---------------+----------+--+--+
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52c893/1/0

Comment: What's the query to return ids/account numbers that have both?

Comment: Can we see expected results?  I'm unsure if you want 2,4,5 in one result set or 2,5 then 4 in two separate queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is necessarily the best approach, but an inner `select` will work:

```
select distinct account_number
from purchases p
where purchase_type = "A" and account_number not in
(
  select account_number
  from purchases
  where purchase_date = p.purchase_date and purchase_type = "B"
)
```

You first collect all ids that have purchase type "B" and then all ids with purchase type "A" that are not in the first collection.

(Assuming your table is `purchases`, `ID` is `id int`, `Purchase Date` is `purchase_date char(1)` and `Date` is `purchase_date char(8)`, but you should be able to adapt the query to your actual columns.

Corresponding fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edf73f/7/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Exists` on the same table:

```
select distinct AccountNumber , Date
from table1 outer_table 
where PurchaseType = 'A' and not exists
  (
    select ID 
    from table1 inner_table 
    where
       PurchaseType = 'B' 
       and inner_table.Date = outer_table.Date 
       and inner_table.AccountNumber = outer_table.AccountNumber
   )
```

Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b84ecd/9

Comment: The question becomes do they want to keep both 5,5, A's so should the result be 3 or 4 records?

Comment: Good point.  I will update to distinct account number / date based on stated problem in OP

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,sum(if(purchase_type='A',1,0)) as sumA,sum(if(purchase_type='B',1,0)) as sumB

from purchases

group by id

having sumA>0 and sumB=0
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edf73f/16

and to get the two request in one:

```
select id,sum(if(purchase_type='A',1,0)) as sumA,sum(if(purchase_type='B',1,0)) as sumB 
from purchases
group by id
having (sumA>0 and sumB=0) OR(sumA=0 and sumB>0 )
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edf73f/18

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use a full outer join where one or the other side is null; but mySQL doesn't support them.  So to simulate: use a left join and then a union (or union all if you want to keep the fact that 1,1,A exists twice.)  and we simply switch the criteria between the joins for the second SQL to union to handle both ways.

DEMO using SQL fiddle in comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52c893/20/0

```
SELECT A.*
FROM purch A
LEFT JOIN purch B
  on A.`Account Number` = B.`Account Number`
  AND B.`Purchase Type`  = 'B'
 WHERE b.`Account Number` is null
   AND A.`Purchase Type`  = 'A'

UNION ALL

SELECT A.*
FROM purch A
LEFT JOIN purch B
  on A.`Account Number` = B.`Account Number`

  AND B.`Purchase Type`  = 'A'
 WHERE b.`Account Number` is null
   AND A.`Purchase Type`  = 'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT   A.account SEPARATOR ', ') AS "accounts"
FROM test A, test B
WHERE A.type='A'
AND A.id=B.id
AND A.date=B.date
AND A.date='2014-03-01'
```

Comment: Result should only have accounts 2,4,5

Comment: Check the new request :)

Comment: why do you want to get 2,4,5 ? 5 IS A, and  4 is B, you cannot get the same result in the query, this is what you decribed at your question, did i missed smtg ?, if i get it you must have 1, 2, 3, 5
, and this is what you get with my query

Comment: "running the first query for A but no B should return 2 and 5. Running the vice-versa query for B but no A should give me 4."  But we don't know if both results are expected at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You get a bit messed up here because MySQL's set arithmetic operations are incomplete. It has `UNION` and `INTERSECT` but not `EXCEPT`.  If it had `EXCEPT` you could do

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Account Number` FROM purch WHERE `Purchase Type` = 'A' 
EXCEPT    /* MySQL fail! */
SELECT DISTINCT `Account Number` FROM purch WHERE `Purchase Type` = 'B'
```

and your problem would be solved.

So you can use the `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` query pattern. It's more verbose but works fine. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52c893/18/0)

```
SELECT  suba.`Account Number`

 FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT `Account Number`
            FROM purch
           WHERE `Purchase Type` = 'A'
       ) suba
  LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT DISTINCT `Account Number`
            FROM purch
           WHERE `Purchase Type` = 'B'
       ) subb ON suba.`Account Number` =  subb.`Account Number`
 WHERE subb.`Account Number` IS NULL
```